# Find a Specific Character in a Field and Replace it with a Phrase

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I've been searching around the internet for an answer to this question for a few hours and I'm not able to find anything. My experience with FoxPro is quite limited. This will probably be 2 questions in one.

First question: I have a list of items and some of these items may contain a comma which is not allowed in the program I'm transferring the data to.

I basically need sort of a statement like this:

```
REPLACE ALL Field1 with STRTRAN(field1, "," , "<break time='250ms' />"
```

Is something like that going to accomplish what I need?

Second Question: I have 5 separate fields that I need the data from to be moved into a new field. Something like this.

Field1:  October
Field2:  21
Field3:  2013
Field4:  5:00
Field5:  PM

FinalField Thank you for your email, your appointment is scheduled for [Field1] [Field2] [Field3] at [Field4] [Field5].

This will be for thousands of records, so I'd like to formulate a statement that would replace them all at once.

```
REPLACE ALL FinalField with STRTRAN(
```

After that I'm not sure what format it needs to be within the parenthesis to properly replace the field with what I need. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question:
What you've written will replace each occurrence of a comma with "<break time='250ms' />".  Not sure that's what you're after.  To simply remove all commas:

REPLACE ALL field1 WITH STRTRAN(field1, [,], [])

will do it.  I like to use the [ ] characters as string delimiters when I'm dealing with commas, quotation marks, etc. - for clarity.

Take a look at the TEXTMERGE() function for the answer to your second question.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I had a feeling I was right with the top section, and I've taken a look at the TEXTMERGE() funtion and I'm hoping this is the solution I needed. Again Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, you can just write an expression like:

```
REPLACE ALL FinalField WITH ;
  "Thank you for your email, your appointment is scheduled for " + ;
  ALLTIRIM(Field1) + " " + TRANSFORM(Field2) + ;
  TRANSFORM(Field3) + " at " + ;
  ALLTRIM(Field4) + ALLTRIM(Field5) + "."
```

This assumes that Field1, Field4 and Field5 are character and Field2 and Field3 are numeric. If that's not so, you'll have to adjust them.

If you're doing a one-time export to another application, you might find it easier to write a SQL query to put all the data into the format you want and then export the cursor that query generates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually used this rather than the TEXTMERGE() function as this is a little easier to understand.